# Is there any way to have console (rogue) mode programs take over only part of the terminal screen?

Tags: command-line, terminal, console

I like the command line because it preserves the context of what I'm doing. But if I use a "rogue" mode program like `vi` or `less`, the whole screen gets taken over.

Is a middle way possible, where the console mode program takes over only half the screen (above or below the shell part)?

I'm borrowing the term "rogue" from [Eric Raymond](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch11s06.html#id2958491):

> Roguelike programs are designed to be run on a system console, an X terminal emulator, or a video display terminal. They use the full screen and support a visual interface style, but with character-cell display rather than graphics and a mouse.

I already use tmux and GNU screen to split the terminal into panes, but I'm looking for a way to stay in one shell session.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation.  You could probably trick curses into thinking the terminal is smaller than it actually is but what would you do with the remaining space *besides* put another screen or tmux split pane in there running a different process?

Comment: dvtm is another possible way, if I understood what you want correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could run your full-screen program in tmux or Screen pane directly, without additional shell session (shell is just another program).

Another way, which I prefer, is to use tiling/stacking window manager like i3 and terminal program urxvt. The latter has very fast daemon/client structure, which allows opening new windows instantly, so you could run any program in new window this way:

```
urxvtc -e <command> <args>
```

This needs to be in a script or a function, really.

New window will take one half, one third, or so on of the screen in default tiling mode. Combined modes are also possible in these WMs.

Comment: Those are also the same command args as `xterm`. For running the rogue program in a new pane, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Template_script_to_run_program_in_new_session_resp._attach_to_existing_one